# Regular Expression to match exactly the digits after the first dot in a string

Tags: regex, bash

I have a two string like the example below,

```
string_1 = XXXXXXX.98.X131.X001
string_2 = XXXXXXX.X131.X001
```

I want to split the string_1 on the 2nd dot as the 1st dot is followed by a digit and
I want to split the string_2 on the 1st dot as the 1st dot is not followed by a digit

Code is as below for

For String_1 as the input:

```
#!/bin/bash
name='XXXXXXX.98.X131.X001'
if [[ $name =~ [/\.\d\.] ]]; then
    name=$(echo $name | cut -d'.' -f -2) 
    echo $name
else
    name=$(echo $name | cut -d'.' -f1)
    echo $name
fi
```

Below is the output

```
XXXXXXX.98
```

For String_2 as the input:

```
#!/bin/bash
name='XXXXXXX.X131.X001'
if [[ $name =~ [/\.\d\.] ]]; then
    name=$(echo $name | cut -d'.' -f -2) 
    echo $name
else
    name=$(echo $name | cut -d'.' -f1)
    echo $name
fi
```

Below is the output

```
XXXXXXX.X131
```

instead of

```
XXXXXXX
```

what is the best way to check if dot is followed digit or a character

Comment: In Bash Regex grammar, `\d` is literal `d`. If you want to refer to numbers, you use `[[:digit:]]+` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) instead.

```
$ name=XXXXXXX.98.X131.X001
$ echo "${name%%.[![:digit:]]*}"
XXXXXXX.98
$ name=XXXXXXX.X131.X001
$ echo "${name%%.[![:digit:]]*}"
XXXXXXX
```

The `%%.[![:digit:]]*` part removes the longest trailing substring that starts with a dot and a non-digit character from `name`.